# When do write inside () or {} on setOnClickListener? Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, mobile, onclicklistener

I have these both examples and I don't understand why you should use colon or curly braces

```
  binding.playButton.setOnClickListener(
            Navigation.createNavigateOnClickListener(R.id.action_titleFragment_to_gameFragment)
    )

   binding.playButton.setOnClickListener { view: View ->
            Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(R.id.action_titleFragment_to_gameFragment)

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it helps, `View.OnClickListener` is an interface, so when you call `setOnClickListener` you're providing an implementation of that interface:

```
binding.playButton.setOnClickListener(object: View.OnClickListener {
    override fun onClick(p0: View?) {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }
})
```

So in this example, you're creating an object (like an anonymous class) that implements the interface, with a body that includes the function you need to override. You're passing this object as a parameter in the `setOnClickListener` method call. (This is basically what's happening in your first example, you're just calling another function to generate the object for you)

---

But because this interface only has a single function in it, you can strip this whole thing down to a lambda, which is like an anonymous function. So long as it matches the signature of the single function in the interface, it's accepted as an implementation!

```
binding.playButton.setOnClickListener({ p0 -> TODO("Not yet implemented") })
```

When it's a single argument like this, you can drop the variable name and it will just be called `it`, if your code needs to refer to it at all (with more than 1 argument you'll need to explicitly name them though)

```
binding.playButton.setOnClickListener({ TODO("Not yet implemented") })
```

That function is held in the curly braces, it's a block of code. So we have both - the parentheses (because we're doing a method call), and the curly braces (delimiting the function we're passing to the method as an argument).

---

But Kotlin also lets us move a function parameter like this outside of the parentheses, if it's the last parameter in the call we're making. So if you're making a list of squares like this:

```
nums = List(4, { it * it })
```

you can move the initialisation function outside to make it neater

```
nums = List(4) { it * it }
```

and when the function is the only parameter, you can drop the parentheses entirely

```
nums.map { it * it } // equivalent to nums.map({it * it})
```

so that's what's happening with your second example - you're creating a lambda that's an implementation of the click listener interface, and passing it into `setOnClickListener`, and because it's the only parameter you're dropping the parentheses and you're just left with the lambda in its curly braces

```
binding.playButton.setOnClickListener { TODO("Not yet implemented") }
```

hope that clears it up! The linter will usually give you some tips and quick fixes to clean things up to the preferred style

Answer (score 1):

First scenario - single click listener which should listen multiple views:

```
val clickListener = { view: View ->
        when (view.tag) { // or view.id
            // ...
        }
    }
binding.playButton.setOnClickListener(clickListener)
binding.pauseButton.setOnClickListener(clickListener)
```

Second scenario - listener which will be used only for one button:

```
binding.playButton.setOnClickListener { view -> 
     startPlaying()
}
```

Looks like you have some king of factory for listeners so first approach is preferable.

Answer (score 0):

simple answer is use braces {} to write a block of code (multiple lines) and use parentheses () to write a single line

Comment: This is incorrect. Curly braces are a lambda function. Parentheses are for passing parameters, not callable code.

Comment: i'm talking in general use, braces it's not exclusive to lambda

Comment: and notice that i start with "simple answer" like you can do playButton.setOnClickListener(v:View->print(v.tag) ) or playButton.setOnClickListener(v:View->{print(v.tag)print(v.tag)print(v.tag)print(v.tag)} );

Comment: Composing functions is a completely different thing than what the OP is asking about, which is calling functions that take an interface argument.